# Multidimensional array to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to convert a multidimensional array/dataframe into a dictionary and having some troubles. I loaded the excel document as a dataframe and trying to work with it that way. However, I am open to using numpy if necessary. I'm restricted to using only numpy or pandas for my assignment though.

I've tried using the pandas `d.to_dict()` methods but can't seem to figure out which one that would bring me the expected result. I can't use `mapdict` or any packages, unfortunately.

The data looks like:

```
  Type Jan Feb
0    a   1   0
1    b   0   1
2    c   1   1
3    d   1   0
```

The desired corresponding output would be a dictionary like:

```
{'A' : ['Jan'], 'B' : ['Feb'], 'C' : ['Jan', 'Feb'], 'D' : ['Jan']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give us your input data but I guess it is what you need .

```
df.to_dict(orient= 'index')
```

if it is not can want give us more information ...

Comment: I think someone edited my post to show you the inputs. Sorry I didn't know how to do it (first time posting here!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't spend much time in pandas to I'm not sure this is the best answer but you can use a comprehension with compress:

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a',1,0],['b',0,1],['c',1,1],['d',1,0]],columns=['type','jan','feb'])
>>> df.head()
type  jan  feb
0    a    1    0
1    b    0    1
2    c    1    1
3    d    1    0
>>> months = ['jan','feb']
>>> [{df.loc[key]['type']: list(compress(months, [v for v in df.loc[key, months]]))} for key in df.index]
[{'a': ['jan']}, {'b': ['feb']}, {'c': ['jan', 'feb']}, {'d': ['jan']}]
```

If there are additional months you could add them to the `months` list.